# Probability random pick bad/good parts for robot

Tags: probability, random-variables

A robot is formed by 6 parts, those parts will be randomly chosen from a box with 15 used parts. The robot will be functional if at least 4 of its 6 parts are in good condition. If 10 of the 15 parts in the box are in good condition, then, what is the probability for the robot to be functional?

First i set that X = Number of components chosen in good condition.
So a robot to be functional must have at least 4 good parts so, $P(X>=4)=P(X=4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6)$.

for $\displaystyle P(X=4)=\frac{\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{15}{6}}$

for $\displaystyle P(X=5)=\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{15}{6}}$

and so on..

Am i doing it right? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! For $P(X=4)$, you need to choose $4$ out of $10$ good parts, AND you need to choose $2$ out of $5$ bad parts.  Both have to be in the numerator.